# grep to match pattern, only if there are some alphanumeric characters after it

Tags: text-processing, grep

How do skip empty comments in the example below? I want `grep` to match `comments`, only if there are some alphanumeric characters after it.

```
$cat file | grep 'Object Name:\|manual_encdomain:\|comments: *'
Object Name: ABC
    comments: This is non emtoy comment
            comments: 
            comments: 
                comments: 
                comments: 
                comments: 
    manual_encdomain: Name: net_1.1.1.1_24 (Table: network_objects)
```

so the desired output is below:

```
Object Name: ABC
    comments: This is non emtoy comment     
    manual_encdomain: Name: net_1.1.1.1_24 (Table: network_objects)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `[[:alnum:]]` character class with one ore more occurrences.

```
grep 'Object Name:\|manual_encdomain:\|comments: [[:alnum:]]\+' in
```

You could use `[0-9A-Za-z]` which is what `[[:alnum:]]` character class is matching.

Or use reverse `grep -v ...` with `[[:space:]]` character class:

```
grep -v 'comments:[[:space:]]*$' in
```

Also note that `grep` itself can read from input file not required use extra `cat file | ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean *if there is at least one alphanumeric character* among the characters that follow it, that would be:

```
<file grep -E 'Object Name:|manual_encdomain:|comments:.*[[:alnum:]]'
```

That is `comments:` followed by any number (`*`) of any character (`.`) followed by an alphanumeric character (or you could use `[^[:space:]]` instead of `[[:alnum:]]` for any character except a spacing one).

Note that `\|` is not standard/portable. Alternation is  a feature of standard extended regular expressions which `grep` understands with `-E` (standardly).

You'd need `cat` if you wanted to concatenate several files. The shell can open the `file` to make it directly `grep`'s stdin (as opposed to a pipe) like above or you could even pass the file name as argument to `grep` for `grep` to open and read it itself.